# how can i use delegate to fill 2D list?

Tags: c#

i have the following Function

```
public string StoredProcedure(string StoredProcedureName,List<List<string>> StoredProcedureParameter,string ReturnValue = null)
{ 
    string functionReturnValue; 
    cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcedureName, conniction(true)); 
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; 
    for (int i = 0; i <= StoredProcedureParameter.Count; i++) 
    { 
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(StoredProcedureParameter[0][i], StoredProcedureParameter[1][i]); 
    }

    int exec_cmd = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar(); 

    if (ReturnValue != null) 
    { 
        SqlParameter prm = new SqlParameter(ReturnValue, SqlDbType.Int); 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(prm).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue; 
        functionReturnValue = prm.ToString(); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        functionReturnValue = exec_cmd.ToString(); 
    } 

    return functionReturnValue; 
}
```

and i need to pass 2D list Parameter to StoredProcedureParameter using delegate and maybe lambda expression

Comment: Lambda expression **is a** delegate.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: What makes you think you need a delegate? What problem are you trying to solve? This sounds a lot like an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @la elah ala allah I think you need an pre-defined event which will get executed with the help of delegate. Am I correct?

Comment: Ok i mean that : i need to call my function like the following

StoredProcedure("StoredProcedurename" , 
here is my quistion like delegate{ how pass 2D list ? } ,
"returnID")

Comment: from another side 

("StoredProcedurename" , 
delegate { how return 2D list to StoredProcedureParameter } ,
 "returnID")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the following.

1. Change the signature of your method to accept delegates:

   ```
   public string StoredProcedure(string StoredProcedureName, Func<List<List<string>>> StoredProcedureParameterFunc, string ReturnValue = null)
   {
       List<List<string>> StoredProcedureParameter = StoredProcedureParameterFunc();
       ... // your original code here
   }
   ```
2. Invoke the method like this:

   ```
   var result = StoredProcedure("SPName", GetLists, "returnID");
   ```

   Where `GetLists` is a new method returning a "2D" list of strings, e.g.:

   ```
   private List<List<string>> GetLists() {
     var result = new List<List<string>>();
     ... // fill result here
     return result;
   }
   ```

Comment: if it possible to set GetLists in line that's more beautiful
as example i need to do some thing like var result = StoredProcedure("SPName", delegate { ... // fill result here } , "returnID"); thanks at all